# Pressure-Temperature water diagram phase function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, graphing-functions

I'm trying to find a analytical expression that describes the pressure-temperature function. The function that I want to describe is the pressure-temperature function where the water is in liquid state, as shown in this log-linear scaled figure:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Phase_diagram_of_water.svg

My target is: for each temperature,pressure, check if with that parameters water is in liquid state.
I tried to compute approximately the function by fitting (by using Matlab, trying interpolation, using cftool and trying to improve the approximation) but I think that my result is wrong. On Matlab I gave vectors of temperature (Kelvin) and pressure (Pascal) and the best approximation characteristic that passes through points is described by:

$y=a \cdot e^{(b \cdot x)}+c \cdot x^6$

where a,b and c are respectively: [$3.51 \cdot 10^{30}$; $0.1092$; $0.208245204973289$].

I thought that, to see if a point(temperature,pressure) is in liquid state of water diagram, I must verify $y - a \cdot e^{(b \cdot x)}+c \cdot x^6 > 0$

I assumed that, since I don't overcome the critical point, the maximum temperature is 647 K, and I assumed that the maximum pressure is about 2000 atm ($2,0265 \cdot 10^8$ Pa).

Where did I wrong? Is there a better way to describe the function of the pressure-temperature characteristic and check if a given point (temperature,pressure) is in liquid state diagram (always in mathematical way)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which curve did you fit using $y=a * e^{(b * x)}+c * x^6$ ?

Comment: Hi Claude. In Matlab I made two arrays, one containing the temperature values (my x) and other containing related pressure values (my y) that made the function delimiting the liquid state area. Then, by cftool of Matlab, I used that expression to interpolate the points (temperature,pressure) defined by the values contained in the two arrays